# How to return multiple photos directly to the current html page with flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to create a function that shows the photos submitted by the user directly on the current page. In a nutshell, What i intended was to make kind of preview function that shows pictures in advance on the current page before the user finally uploads them.
I used pandas for buliding database, and photos are saved as the name of index number in  **static/img** root.

I'm confused how to print out only the pictures that the user has just uploaded, out of the many pictures in the img folder.

**flask__init__**

```
 @app.route("/apply", methods=['POST'])
    def apply():
    ctg = request.form.get('ctg_select')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file")
        for f in uploaded_files:
            f.save("helloflask/static/img/{}.jpeg".format(database.now_index()))
            database.save(ctg)
    return redirect(url_for('enroll', data_list=uploaded_files))
```

**database**

```
import pandas as pd

def save(ctg):
    idx = len(pd.read_csv("database.csv"))
    new_df = pd.DataFrame({"catagorize" : ctg}, 
                          index = [idx])
    new_df.to_csv("database.csv", mode="a", header=False)
    return None

def now_index():
    df = pd.read_csv("database.csv")
    return len(df)
```

**HTML**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}   
{% block main%}

<h1 class="display-1" style="margin:20">Enroll your items</h1>

{% for img in data_list %}
<img src="" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
{% endfor %}

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{url_for('apply')}}">
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple">
    <div class="form-floating">
        <select name="ctg_select" class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
            <option disabled selected value>Categorizes</option>
            <option value="sports">Sports</option>
            <option value="music">Music</option>
            <option value="electronic">Electronics</option>
        </select>
        <label for="floatingSelect">Select categorize</label>
    </div>
    <label for="customRange3" class="form-label">Product status</label>
        <input name="status_range" type="range" class="form-range" min="0" max="5" step="0.5" id="range">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary"> Submit </button>
</form>  
{% endblock %}
```

**database.csv**

```
index, categories
    0,electronic
    1,electronic
    2,electronic
    3,electronic
    4,electronic
    5,electronic
    6,electronic
    7,electronic
    8,electronic
    9,electronic
    10,electronic
```

Comment: in database/dataframe you should keep filename with user name or with user unique `cookie` and when users connect then you should use `cookie` to get only images with this cookie in database/dataframe

Comment: or maybe you should create list with names `"helloflask/static/img/{}.jpeg".` and send it to template